# Returning an object instead of desired output in Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps

I am working on a Dapp and facing some issues.
I have created a contract which has a function as

```
function getId() public view returns (uint8){
 return getMyId[msg.sender];
}
```

I am calling the same in the front end and desire that id should be returned from the contract and be stored in the variable. The code in App.js is as follows

```
const myId = await this.state.dstock.methods.getId.call({ from: this.state.account }); 
console.log("myId",myId);
```

This is returning something unexpected

[image]

Kindly provide a suitable solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing parenthesis in the method call. The following should work:

```
const myId = await this.state.dstock.methods.getId().call({ from: this.state.account });
```

Comment: Can you also please explain why I was getting an object returned in the former case and not any error?

Comment: @Shrey not sure if I could pin it down. `web3.methods` has many ways for how it lets you access your desired method. For example, you could try `this.state.dstock.methods["getId()"]().call({ from: this.state.account })` by method with parameter, or with the abi-encoded form. I think if you print both `this.state.dstock.methods.getId()` and `this.state.dstock.methods.getId` and compare, you'll see how `.call()` exists on both layers, as web3 is very flexible and doesn't confine you to the way you should formulate the method call.

Comment: Furthermore, I believe you might also be able to make a correct method call by using: `await this.state.dstock.methods.getId.call().call({ from: this.state.account });`

Comment: Not sure on the latter, so please try it and come back with some feedback.